# iPhone MediaPlayer - Fullscreen?

Tags: iphone, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

I've gone through a bunch of other examples, but I cannot get a video to load full screen in a viewController.

I'm able to get it to load... but not launch in full screen.

The code is below. Thanks!

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {     
    NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
    }


- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];    
    [player autorelease];
    }
```

Edit: Full screen fixed... I just had to add: moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

Now it adds an odd image to my status bar.. see attached photo.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by `fullscreen` means, but I normally see this line

```
  [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

written with `bounds` as an argument like this

```
[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.bounds];
```

or

```
 [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

depending on what type of object `self` is.

Comment: Thanks Walter... what I mean by fullscreen is for the "Done" button to show on launch, instead of having to tap the fullscreen button first.

Comment: Thanks Walter... I added `moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;` which seems to kind of fix it. Now I get a weird image in my status bar... see my updated question for an image.